# Perl - Net::SFTP::Foreign

Tags: perl

I am trying to write an upload script in Perl , using Net::SFTP::Foreign.

I am having issue with checking if the directory exists, and if it does not, creating it.

Net::SFTP::Foreign seems to just error and close the connection if the directory doesn't exist, and never runs the "else"

You can see the code below, can aanyone see where im going wrong?

```
sub uploadtoftp
{
use Net::SFTP::Foreign;
use File::Basename;
use warnings;

  my $host=$_[0];
  my $user=$_[1];
  my $pw=$_[2];


   my $home_directory ="/home/testuser";
  my $remote_path=$home_directory."/".$name."/".$destination_dir;



  if (my $ftp = Net::SFTP::Foreign->new($host,
                                   user => $user,
                                   password => $pw,
                                   autodie => 0))
  {

      my $destination_dir_proceed=0;


        $ftp->find("$remote_path", on_error => sub { print "Creating directory\n"; $ftp->mkdir("$remote_path")  });
        print $ftp->error;


        if($ftp->opendir($remote_path)) 
        {
          $destination_dir_proceed=1;
        }


        if($destination_dir_proceed==1) 
        {
        # --- loop through file list and upload all new files
        foreach $filename (split(/ /, $file_list)) 
        {
          $ftp->put($filename,$remote_path.$filename);

        }


        }

      else
      {
        print "cannot reach directory $remote_path\n";
      }


  }




} # end subroutine uploadtoftp()
```

Answer (score 2):

When you instantiated the Net::SFTP::Foreign object, you created it with `autodie  => 1`.

[Autodie](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SFTP::Foreign#autodie-mode) will "promote non-recoverable errors to execptions automatically".

You can remove the autodie line and be OK as long as you're checking for status  regularly throughout the script.

If there are places you want to die at, you can use [die_on_error](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SFTP::Foreign#die_on_error) after you've made a request

Comment: Hi, this worked for the inital problem, however it is still not creating the directory.

Comment: Is there a new error that's populated when you try to create the directory?

Comment: Nope, just my one that is printed " cannot reach directory "  which means it wasnt created,

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following logic to create the folder:

```
$ftp->find("$remote_path", on_error => sub { print "Creating directory\n"; $ftp->mkdir("$remote_path") });
```

if you do not need print statement:

```
$ftp->find("$remote_path", on_error => sub { $ftp->mkdir("$remote_path") });
```

If you need to create all missing folders in the path, this should work (I cannot currently test it, but the idea seems correct).

```
my $home_directory ="home/testuser";
my $remote_path=$home_directory."/".$name."/".$destination_dir;

my $currentPath = '';
foreach my $directory (split '/', $remote_path) {
    $currentPath = "$currentPath/$directory";
    $ftp->find("$currentPath", on_error => sub { print "Creating directory\n"; $ftp->mkdir("$currentPath") });
}
```

Comment: Tried this, it says "creating directory" but no directory is created.

Comment: print out $remote_path and see if you can CD to the directory.

Comment: what is the value of $name?

Comment: Also print error see what the actial error is: print $ftp->error;

Comment: print $ftp-error just shows a 0.    the value of $name is is seen below in the full error , as I print out the full $remote_path in my error. I've updated the main code to show what I'm doing,
Creating directory
0cannot reach directory /home/testuser/TESTING_MYTESTDIR/20180919_TESTING_MYTESTDIR. I have also tried just doing this -   $ftp->mkdir($remote_path);   and this does not error, but no directory is created. I feel like I'm doing everything right...

Comment: Try to manually connect to FTP and manually create the directory to make sure you are able to do so. The code I provided definitely works. If it does not create the folder, either there is an issue with the path or permissions.

Comment: I thought this, but I then tried it as root and same issue.  I am testing on locahost though,  I tried this - sftp testuser@localhost  and was able to "mkdir test" and this creates the test directory....... I've tried just this "$ftp->mkdir($remote_path);" and even that does not work.  Update - $ftp->mkdir("testing12345");  working fine....doesn't seem to like the variable..?

Comment: I've figured out what the issue is..... You can create 1 directory, but can't create it two. e.g test/  works but test/test2  wont, until test/ exists.... Strange, i wonder if there is a max-depth option or something similar.  I have it to work by creating each directory individually however now its adding the below to the structure   - desired structure  /home/testuser/testing/testingdir/ actual structure /home/testuser/testing/testingdir/home/sftp/testing/testingdir  ¬_¬